# What is the difference between setState and GetX in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I am just looking forward to understanding the difference between using a normal `setState(() {})` and the `update()` method of the `Getx` package.

As much as I can see from the practical point of view when `setState(() {])` is used the whole page is rebuilt but when GetX has used only the part of .obs is rebuilt. What I want to understand is more in-depth difference.

Comment: check [List of state management approaches](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setState will refresh the whole widget. But using the Getx you can refresh the particular widget.

More you can find from this link : [Getx Controller](https://www.kindacode.com/article/using-getx-get-for-state-management-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 1):

`Getx`'s state manager, is a tool that let you control and manage your widget state from a separate place, which is the `GetxController`.

The `Getx` state management widgets, like `GetBuilder()`, `Getx()`, `Obx()`... are `StatfulWidget`s and under the hood, they also use a normal `SetState(() {})`, but the implementation of calling them is really different than a usual `setState(() {})` call.

As example, the `GetBuilder()` :

```
class GetBuilder<T extends GetxController> extends StatefulWidget {
  final GetControllerBuilder<T> builder;
  final bool global;
  final Object? id;
  final String? tag;
  final bool autoRemove;
  final bool assignId;
  final Object Function(T value)? 
  /*...*/
```

and under the hood, it updates the state by getting a method like this :

```
  void getUpdate() {
    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }
```

then store it in `Map` we call it from the controller with an `update()`.

Your sentence:

> As much as I can see from a practical point of view when setState is used the whole page is rebuilt but when GetX has used only the part of .obs is rebuilt

is wrong!

Try wrapping your whole page with a `GetBuilder` and call the `update()` from its controller, and you will have a full rebuild for the whole page because it's just a normal `StatefulWidget` that will be rebuilt by calling its `build()` method again and again...

You face the whole page state update because you wrap the whole of it with a `StatfulWidget`, the same thing with `GetBuilder()`, `Obx()`...

There is a `Flutter` builder widget that let you also manage the state of its child just locally, which is [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html), give it a quick check and I recommend that you play with it to understand that approach of using a builder widget to update the state.

Besides that `Getx` gives you the ability to separate your logic and state management into the `GetxController`, it let you control which widget to update exactly with its own custom mechanisms like using the `update()` method ( which calls a normal SetState(() {}) ) with a specific `id`, like this:

```
update([id1, id2, id3]);
```

Under the hood search over a `Map` where it stores all the `SetState(() {})` that it got from the `Getx`'s `GetBuilder()`, then look for what matches that `id`, then call only what belongs to it, and this what causes that widget having one of those `id` will be updated, and other widgets will not.

you can check more about how `Getx` works with a quick reads of its source code, I guess it will be very helpful for you.